# Error end text missing on iTextSharp after some text inserts

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm trying to create a pdf with iTextSharp but after I insert some text on the pdf, the pdf gets corrupted and displays this nasty popup on a Pdf Reader (see link)

[Img Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV4oL.png)

I've also used another program to check out what was the error problem and it seems the iText library stops adding begin/end blocks when new text is insert

[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9jmT.png)

I'm using the latest version of iTextSharp (v.5.5.8.0)
And this is the simple code I use

```
Sub Main()
    Dim objPageSize As iTextSharp.text.Rectangle
    Dim objDocument As Document
    Dim objWriter As pdf.PdfWriter

    objPageSize = New Rectangle(842, 595)
    objDocument = New Document(objPageSize, 50, 50, 50, 50)
    objWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(objDocument, New System.IO.FileStream("test.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    Call objDocument.Open()
    objWriter.Open()
    objWriter.DirectContent.BeginText()

    For i As Integer = 0 To 85
        Dim ct As ColumnText = New ColumnText(objWriter.DirectContent)
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(1, i * 5, 100, 100, 0, Element.ALIGN_LEFT)
        Dim phrase As Phrase = New Phrase("hello", FontFactory.GetFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, False, 4))
        ct.SetText(phrase)
        ct.Go()
    Next


    objWriter.DirectContent.EndText()
    objDocument.Close()
    objWriter.Close()


End Sub
```

It look like a bug on the library.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I just found the answer myself.

I'll post it here for any other people might help.

You don't need to call
objWriter.DirectContent.BeginText()
and 
objWriter.DirectContent.EndText()

The ColumnText class does it for you